# How to implement a search option in dropdown in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, nebular

I am facing some issues on implementing a filter search field in select options. I have searched for it but could not find the right answer. 
I do not want to use the angular material because I am using Nebular. Can anyone help me to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Nebular has an autocomplete component that allows you to do exactly what you need.
[Autocomplete](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/5.1.x/docs/components/autocomplete/overview#nbautocompletedirective)

Answer (score -4):

***.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nb-select-placeholder',
  templateUrl: './select-placeholder.component.html',
})
export class SelectPlaceholderComponent {
}
```

***.html**

```
<nb-card size="small">
  <nb-card-body>
    <nb-select placeholder="Placeholder">
      <nb-option value="1">Option 1</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="2">Option 2</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="3">Option 3</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="4">Option 4</nb-option>
    </nb-select>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

**Reference:**

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/select/overview#nbselectcomponent